# Exclude certain Activity types on Activities tab

Tags: activities

On the Activities tab of contacts, there is the possibility to filter which activity types are displayed.

Is there any way to set this filter by default?

Or another way to exclude Contribution Activities from that tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way of doing this through the user interface. However once a user sets the activity type filter, this should persist for that user, as it gets saved as a user preference. See [Save user preferences for filtering Activities tab listings](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-11761).

To set the default value of the filter, I would try using the [buildForm hook](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_buildForm).

Comment: Note: if you find your exclude/include filters are NOT saving (i.e. you have to set them every time) then it's probably that you have the "**Preserve activity filters as a user preference**" tickbox un-ticked; find that on the **Administer » Customise data and screens » Display Preferences**. After turning that on, your preferences should stick for your user.

Answer (score 1):

My Civi did not save the preference (actually it completely ignored this filter)
But it turns out it was a bug in my CiviCRM installation. It was fixed by updating to a newer version.